# gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.2.0: ERROR: Job failed: exit code 252

Tags: mongodb, docker, jobs, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running my tests inside a docker image on a docker gitlab executor. The logs are looking like this:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.2.0
.
.
<after_script called>
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 252
```

The last thing I am doing in my job script (shell) is a call to mongo eval
My after_script for this job just has a docker rm -f imagename like so:

```
after_script:
- docker rm -f imagename
```

First of all, I cannot find any concrete reference to this error code #. I don't know if it is a mongo eval error code or gitlab ci. My best guess is gitlab ci because that script works fine if run directly on the build machine. Also, the after_script is executed

I added the following in the beginning of my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
variables:
  CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
```

But all I am seeing is:

```
+ docker rm -f imagename
imagename
+ exit 0
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 252
```

Any help or any clue is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My mongo eval connection was failing because my mongo command was incorrect. I

1. Left the docker container running by using && tail -f /dev/null in my docker CMD.
2. I shelled in with $docker exec -it
3. Ran my script and executed the mongo eval section step by step again

Getting a connection fail for the wrong mongo eval javascript threw me off :/